# Mock Mssparkutils locally for Pytest?

Tags: azure, pyspark, pytest, azure-synapse

Im trying to mock Mssparkutils locally.

For example:

```
def list_files(path):
  mssparkutils.fs.ls(path)
```

How can I mock it?

I found a repo for dbutils but not for Mssparkutils.

I tried using patch (Mssparkutils) but I get a name Mssparkutils not found error when running pytest my_test.py file.

I assume because Mssparkutils is not defined anywhere as a module or function it problematic to mock it. The solution for dbutils I found is also add dbutils as a parameter to the function. But since the function is in production, I cant just change it.

Comment: Could you please provide the error what you are getting?

Comment: Done, I get a name Mssparkutils not found error

Comment: Mssparkutils is built in package in synapse notebook. It is not possible to work with it in local environment.

Comment: I know, that's why I want to mock it for unittesting using pytest.

Comment: Like this solution for dbutils but they have dbutils as parameter in the function and I can't modify the original function. I can only mock it: https://community.databricks.com/t5/data-engineering/python-mocking-dbutils-in-unittests/td-p/24660